# Somar valor com angularjs no ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<li ng-repeat="gasto in gastos">
    R${{ gasto.valor }} - {{ gasto.descricao }}
</li>
```

Isto imprime na tela os gastos e a descrição, porém gostaria de somar os gastos, ou seja fazer um total, tipo isso:

```
total += gasto.valor
```

Como é o jeito certo de fazer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem várias formas de fazer isso.

Se você só quiser mostrar o valor na view, pode aproveitar a dinamicidade do JavaScript e criar uma variável na própria view usando o `ng-init`.

Exemplo:

```js
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp').controller('mainController', mainController);

function mainController($scope){  
  this.gastos = [{ valor: 1, descricao: 'Gasto 1' }, 
                 { valor: 2, descricao: 'Gasto 2' }, 
                 { valor: 3, descricao: 'Gasto 3' }];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="mainController as ctrl">
    <li ng-repeat="gasto in ctrl.gastos" ng-init="ctrl.totalGasto = ctrl.totalGasto + gasto.valor">
      R$ {{gasto.valor }} - {{ gasto.descricao }}
    </li>
    <br>
    Total: R$: {{ctrl.totalGasto}}
  </div>
</div>
```

### Dica

Você pode usar o filtro [`currency`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency) quando for trabalhar com valores. Isso vai possibilitar trabalhar com internacionalização e com casas decimais.

Na view, ficaria algo como

```
{{ ctrl.totalGasto | currency }}
```